# Postgresql select column with minimum value of hierarchical parents

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

Having a table like this

```
                       Table "public.access_level"
  Column   |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 uid       | uuid    | not null  | plain    |              |
 parent_id | integer | not null  | plain    |              |
 child_id  | integer | not null  | plain    |              |
 level     | integer | not null  | plain    |              |
 entity    | text    |           | extended |              |
```

and rows like this (uid column eliminated)

```
 parent_id | child_id | level | entity
-----------+----------+-------+--------
        11 |       22 |     4 | a
        22 |       33 |     5 | a
        33 |       44 |     6 | a
        11 |       22 |     7 | b
        22 |       33 |     4 | b
        33 |       44 |     5 | b
```

I would like an output which returns `level` value for each row based on minimum value of `level` of parents distinctive to each `entity`.
Here is my desired output:

```
 parent_id | child_id | level | entity
-----------+----------+-------+--------
        11 |       22 |     4 | a
        22 |       33 |     4 | a
        33 |       44 |     4 | a
        11 |       22 |     7 | b
        22 |       33 |     4 | b
        33 |       44 |     4 | b
```

A recursive approach is desirable as hierarchies depth is not fixed.

***Note:***(parent_id,child_id,entity) is unique in the table

Actually parent_id and child_id are users. a parent gives a child a level of access for an entity. Then the child user can give a level of access to another child of its own. At some point, the parent of a parent may change the access level if its child. now all deeper children have to have access level not more than that. It could not be implemented using a trigger to update the corresponding rows because the ***parent of parent*** may rollback changes.

A Scenario:

- 11,22,7,b means user-11 gives user-22 the `level` of 7 to `b` entity.
- Now user-22 gives the user-33 level of ***5*** to `b` entity at some point
- then user-33 give user-44 the level of ***5*** to `b` entity.
- ***Important:*** user-22 changes access level of `b` to ***4*** for the user-33 which is what you see in example table
- access level of user-33 to user-44 for `b` entity **should** remain 5 in the table

But I want the a query which will return 4 for that column as if I do it recursively for all children of user-22 which got the level more than 4.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a partition by: `min(level) over (partition by parent_id)`. You can add more columns to the partition by, think of it as a `group by`.

Comment: @Viorel, that is not achievable by partitioning. think as each entity has a tree, for each node of the tree I want to return the minimum of ```level``` traversing the tree to the root

Comment: That level column makes it look like it is already a result of a recursive query and you could partition by entity. The link between the data and the desired output is not very clear to me, why does parent 33 for entity b end up with a level of 4, whereas parent 11 for entity b has a level of 7?

Comment: @Viorel, updated my answer with some more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial part of the recursive query finds roots (nodes without parents), in the recursive part we simply choose a less level for an entity:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select parent_id, child_id, level, entity
    from access_level t
    where not exists (
        select from access_level l
        where l.child_id = t.parent_id)
union all
    select t.parent_id, t.child_id, least(c.level, t.level), t.entity
    from cte c
    join access_level t
    on t.parent_id = c.child_id and t.entity = c.entity
)
select *
from cte
order by entity, parent_id
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3693579f122bb396a41521a84b59b9a2)